# PHP: unserialize(): Error at offset 757 of 784 bytes

Tags: php

why does it return an "unserialize(): Error at offset 757 of 784 bytes" i was just adding permission to the serialized string in the database here is my string

database: permission row

Super Admin:

```
a:32:{i:0;s:10:"createUser";i:1;s:10:"updateUser";i:2;s:8:"viewUser";i:3;s:10:"deleteUser";i:4;s:11:"createGroup";i:5;s:11:"updateGroup";i:6;s:9:"viewGroup";i:7;s:11:"deleteGroup";i:8;s:11:"createStore";i:9;s:11:"updateStore";i:10;s:9:"viewStore";i:11;s:11:"deleteStore";i:12;s:11:"createTable";i:13;s:11:"updateTable";i:14;s:9:"viewTable";i:15;s:11:"deleteTable";i:16;s:14:"createCategory";i:17;s:14:"updateCategory";i:18;s:12:"viewCategory";i:19;s:14:"deleteCategory";i:20;s:13:"createProduct";i:21;s:13:"updateProduct";i:22;s:11:"viewProduct";i:23;s:13:"deleteProduct";i:24;s:11:"createOrder";i:25;s:11:"updateOrder";i:26;s:9:"viewOrder";i:27;s:11:"deleteOrder";i:28;s:10:"viewReport";i:29;s:13:"updateCompany";i:30;s:11:"viewProfile";i:31;s:13:"updateSetting";}
```

Cashier:

```
a:10:{i:0;s:8:"viewFile";i:1;s:9:"viewStore";i:2;s:11:"updateTable";i:3;s:9:"viewTable";i:4;s:11:"createOrder";i:5;s:11:"updateOrder";i:6;s:9:"viewOrder";i:7;s:11:"deleteOrder";i:8;s:10:"viewReport";i:9;s:11:"viewProfile";}
```

Manager:

```
a:20:{i:0;s:8:"viewFile";i:1;s:8:"viewUser";i:2;s:11:"createGroup";i:3;s:11:"updateGroup";i:4;s:9:"viewGroup";i:5;s:11:"deleteGroup";i:6;s:9:"viewStore";i:7;s:11:"createTable";i:8;s:11:"updateTable";i:9;s:9:"viewTable";i:10;s:11:"deleteTable";i:11;s:14:"updateCategory";i:12;s:13:"createProduct";i:13;s:13:"updateProduct";i:14;s:11:"viewProduct";i:15;s:13:"deleteProduct";i:16;s:9:"viewOrder";i:17;s:11:"deleteOrder";i:18;s:10:"viewReport";i:19;s:11:"viewProfile";}
```

My_controller.php:

```
$group_data = array();
if(empty($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))) {
    $session_data = array('logged_in' => FALSE);
    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
}
else {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->load->model('model_groups');
    $group_data = $this->model_groups->getUserGroupByUserId($user_id);
    
    $this->data['user_permission'] = unserialize($group_data['permission']);

    $this->permission = unserialize($group_data['permission']);
}
```

as you can see there was an i:0;s:8:"viewFile"; in the cashier and the manager and in my web you cannot manipulate the super admin permission, so i try the manual in the localhost phpmyadmin i add the line "i:0;s:8:"viewFile";" just like in the cashier and manager and then i got the "unserialize(): Error at offset 757 of 784 bytes". what seems the error here and how can i manipulate the super admin permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to increment the array count at the beginning of the string from 32 to 33 because you are adding another occurance.

So the Super Admin started as

```
a:32:{i:0;s:10:"createUser"; . . .
```

and when you add another occurance to the array you must increment 32 into 33

```
a:33:{i:0;s:8:"viewFile";i:0;s:10:"createUser"; . . .
```